# Spring WebFlux - decoding/parsing "multipart/related" request support

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux, multipart

The reactive-stack web framework, Spring WebFlux, provides a convenient client-side MultipartBodyBuilder API to prepare the body of a multipart request for use with the reactive WebClient.

However on reviewing Spring WebFlux documentation for decoding/parsing multipart requests on a server such as Netty, it seems that just "*multipart/form-data*" content is supported (see [webflux-multipart](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web-reactive.html#webflux-multipart) and [webflux-codecs-multipart](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web-reactive.html#webflux-codecs-multipart)).
There appears to be no mention of "**multipart/related**" content.

For information, an example HTTP 2-part "multipart/related" message would look like:

```
POST /example.com/send-mpr HTTP/2 Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary=----Boundary
Content-Length: ...
 
------Boundary
Content-Type: application/json
{
   "contentId": "<id@vendor.com>"
}
------Boundary
Content-Type: application/specific
Content-Id: <id@vendor.com>
[ ... Message binary data ... ]
------Boundary
```

It is not clear if/how the decoding/parsing of such "multipart/related" requests are supported in Spring WebFlux.

- if supported, are there documented examples (annotated controller, required config etc) to reference?
- if not, is it planned in later releases?